# How can I create a function that will accept both Num and Maybe Num?

Tags: haskell

I'm currently learning about typeclasses in Haskell, and now im trying to create a increment function that works on both Maybe's and Num's. However, I'm kinda stuck at the moment. Can someone help me in the right direction? (error below)

Edit: I'm using -XUndecidableInstances and -XFlexibleInstances as arguments during compilation as recommended by the compiler, considering -XOverlappingInstances (as suggested in the comments) is both deprecated and doesn't seem to work.

```
-- maybenum.hs
class SomeNum a where
  inc' :: a -> Int

instance Num a => SomeNum a where
  inc' n = inc' (Just n)

instance Num a => SomeNum (Maybe a) where
  inc' Nothing = 1
  inc' (Just n) = n + 1

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ inc' (Just 0)
  print $ inc' 5
  print $ inc' Nothing
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( maybenum.hs, maybenum.o )

maybenum.hs:5:12: error:
    • Overlapping instances for SomeNum (Maybe a)
        arising from a use of ‘inc'’
      Matching instances:
        instance Num a => SomeNum a -- Defined at maybenum.hs:4:10
        instance Num a => SomeNum (Maybe a) -- Defined at maybenum.hs:7:10
    • In the expression: inc' (Just n)
      In an equation for ‘inc'’: inc' n = inc' (Just n)
      In the instance declaration for ‘SomeNum a’

maybenum.hs:9:19: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘a’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the instance declaration at maybenum.hs:7:10
    • In the expression: n + 1
      In an equation for ‘inc'’: inc' (Just n) = n + 1
      In the instance declaration for ‘SomeNum (Maybe a)’
    • Relevant bindings include
        n :: a (bound at maybenum.hs:9:14)
        inc' :: Maybe a -> Int (bound at maybenum.hs:8:3)

maybenum.hs:13:11: error:
    • Overlapping instances for SomeNum (Maybe a1)
        arising from a use of ‘inc'’
      Matching instances:
        instance Num a => SomeNum a -- Defined at maybenum.hs:4:10
        instance Num a => SomeNum (Maybe a) -- Defined at maybenum.hs:7:10
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘inc' (Just 0)’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: print $ inc' (Just 0)
      In the expression:
        do { print $ inc' (Just 0);
             print $ inc' 5;
             print $ inc' Nothing }

maybenum.hs:13:22: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a1’ arising from the literal ‘0’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Num a1)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a1’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
        instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        ...plus two others
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the first argument of ‘Just’, namely ‘0’
      In the first argument of ‘inc'’, namely ‘(Just 0)’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘inc' (Just 0)’

maybenum.hs:14:11: error:
    • Overlapping instances for SomeNum a0 arising from a use of ‘inc'’
      Matching instances:
        instance Num a => SomeNum a -- Defined at maybenum.hs:4:10
        instance Num a => SomeNum (Maybe a) -- Defined at maybenum.hs:7:10
      (The choice depends on the instantiation of ‘a0’
       To pick the first instance above, use IncoherentInstances
       when compiling the other instance declarations)
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘inc' 5’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: print $ inc' 5
      In the expression:
        do { print $ inc' (Just 0);
             print $ inc' 5;
             print $ inc' Nothing }

maybenum.hs:14:16: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from the literal ‘5’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Num a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
        instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        ...plus two others
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the first argument of ‘inc'’, namely ‘5’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘inc' 5’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: print $ inc' 5

maybenum.hs:15:11: error:
    • Overlapping instances for SomeNum (Maybe a2)
        arising from a use of ‘inc'’
      Matching instances:
        instance Num a => SomeNum a -- Defined at maybenum.hs:4:10
        instance Num a => SomeNum (Maybe a) -- Defined at maybenum.hs:7:10
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘inc' Nothing’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: print $ inc' Nothing
      In the expression:
        do { print $ inc' (Just 0);
             print $ inc' 5;
             print $ inc' Nothing }
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? By the looks of it you've done exactly that. Why doesn't the solution you have here work?

Comment: @AJFarmar Seems like this'll trigger errors about overlapping instances

Comment: @gallais True, but this can be solved with `-XOverlappingInstances` or `-XIncoherentInstances`. This error wasn't addressed in the question, so I assumed that the problem was elsewhere. So, what is the goal here?

Comment: Thank you for your edit. However, in your error, I can see that you've left out crucial code, specifically that you defined a `Num` instance for `Maybe`s. I've managed to get your code to work, with a few changes; I'll post this as an answer.

Comment: I suggest you avoid all this overlapping business. Just use `inc <$> x` to get under the functor and save everyone the overlapping headaches.

Comment: Unless you are explicitly trying to see what you can do with type classes, I would recommend using a regular function `inc' :: Num a => a -> a` defined as `inc n = n + 1`, then using `maybe 1 inc` to operate on `Num a => Maybe a` values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the adjusted code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}

class SomeNum a where
  inc' :: a -> Int

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} Integral a => SomeNum a where
  inc' n = fromIntegral n + 1

instance Integral a => SomeNum (Maybe a) where
  inc' Nothing  = 1
  inc' (Just n) = fromIntegral n + 1
```

This works as I think you intended:

```
λ> inc' 1
2
λ> inc' (Just 1)
2
λ> inc' Nothing
1
```

---

I have made a few changes based on what I think you intended with this code. Here is an explanation of each:

### The first change: `{-# OVERLAPPABLE #-}`:

You were right to say that `-XOverlappingInstances` is deprecated, but you didn't notice that it was deprecated in favour of `{#- OVERLAPPABLE #-}`. This is what I've added:

```
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (...)
```

This is a necessary addition since you have defined a separate instance of `Num` for `Maybe`s, which causes the clash you experience. This isn't actually necessary with the changes I've made, but if you do indeed change the restriction back from `Integral` to `Num` again, this will save your fall.

### The second change: `Integral a =>`

You can't just convert from a `Num` to an `Int`, as your `inc'` function seems to suggest (remember that `Float` is an instance of `Num`.) So, I adjusted the restriction:

```
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} Integral a => SomeNum a where
  inc' n = fromIntegral n + 1
```

This also noticeable simplifies the `inc'` implementation. Note the use of `fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`. I'm not entirely sure if this is intended, but I you haven't specified so I'm guessing.

---

I hope this helps. If this isn't exactly as you intended it to be, please try to adjust it on your own and explore how these language extensions behave.

Comment: I'm halfway through the Learn You a Haskell for Great Good book, so I wasn't yet familiar with the concept of pragma's. This is what I was trying to do. Thank you!

Comment: @Praetore I'm very glad I could help.